# changing the last commit message without committing newest changes

Tags: git

My ideal workflow would consist of the following steps

1. edit the code
2. compile
3. git commit -a -m "commit message"
4. start running the new binaries, tests, etc. (may take 10+ minutes)
5. start new changes, while the binaries are still running
6. when step # 4 is finished, edit the commit message from step # 3, **without committing the changes introduced in step # 5**, by adding, say, "test FOO failed"

I cannot use `git commit -a --amend -m "new commit message"`, because this commits the new changes as well. I'm not sure that I want to bother with staging or branching. I wish I could just edit the commit message without committing any new changes. Is it possible?

Comment: stash your current changes, amend the last commit, pop your changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no need to stash or do anything else here.

`git commit --amend -m 'Your new message.'`

will not commit any new changes (note the lack of `-a` flag), provided that you haven't explicitly added them to the index (using `git add`, for example).

Comment: This is very close to what I want, but is there a way to totally rewrite the old commit message instead of just adding a new one to the log (to keep the commit log cleaner) ?

Comment: I don't understand the question - running the command I mentioned will not create a new commit (or a new message in the log, unless you're talking about the reflog, which shouldn't matter).

Comment: I was referring to whatever `gitk --all` is showing. Anyhow, it'd be nice to make that history cleaner. (But I'll accept your answer - thanks!)

Comment: Ah. Just had a look at `gitk` output -- it looks like this is happening when you have multiple references pointing at the same initial commit (for example if you've pushed the commit to a remote before amending it). When you change this, it will show up as a new log entry, because you actually have created a new commit with your new message, so your history has diverged. Do this carefully; this will also cause a bump when you try to push (requiring some form of resolution: merge or rebase, or else a force push to overwrite the remote history).

Comment: Have also just noticed that I made a mistake in my previous comment " will not create a new commit" is strictly false. What I meant to say was "it will not append an additional commit onto the history of your HEAD". Creating a new commit is precisely what it does, but it updates the current reference so that the previous commit is unreachable -- unless you're in the situation I just described with multiple references pointing at that commit (all of them would have to be updated in order for the old commit to disappear from the --all view).

Answer (score 4):

Just:

```
$ git stash
$ git commit --amend -m "Your Modified Message"
$ git stash apply
```

Comment: By the way, I'd like to use `git stash drop` after applied the stash. :)

Comment: You also need to quit the editor (vim) and then restart it, right? It seems a bit laborious. Isn't it possible to just edit a string in the git data datastructure?

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 You can do this work while editing your file either, there's no need to quit the vim. Just make sure that you've added `.*.sw[po]` to `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I tried your approach. Git created 4 entries in the log instead of 1: "old message"; "index on $branch"; "WIP on $branch"; "new message". This is rather unsatisfying. Further, Vim gives warnings asking me whether to reload the changed files. I wish there was a way to just change the commit message without touching anything else.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 _'I wish there was a way to just change the commit message without touching anything else.'_ Ya, I think so. I tried to modified __HEAD__ file but without any lucky.. I found that every time I use `--amend`, it'll create a new log with format of `<origin sha> <new sha> <username> <email> <time> <time zone> commit (amend): <new message>`, just editing does not work. Well, more difficulty than I thought..

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
git rebase -i HEAD^
```

This will open up your text editor and let's you change the last commit. You need to replace the word `pick` in the beginning of the line with `reword`, save the file and exit. After that a new text editor will open up that let's you change the commit message.

That sounds a bit more work than the suggested `git commit --amend` approach, but works also for older commites. So if you found that you want to change two messages in the last ten commits, you can run `git rebase -i HEAD~10` and change the word `pick` again into `reword` and change both of those messages.

Just for the curious: `-i` stands for *interactive rebasing*.